# Program solving 8-queen problem using permutation

Tags: c#, algorithm, n-queens

I have to write a program to solve the 8 queen problem using permutations. My program can generate all possible permutations for 8 digits, but I don't know why it still prints the permutations that are note the solutions of the 8 queen problem.

This is my code below. A class generating permutations and printing the ones that are solutions to the problem:

```
class formPermut
{
    int[] row = new int[8];
    int ifGoodPermutation = 1;

    public void swapNumbers(ref int a, ref int b)
    {
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

    public void PrintPermutation(int[] list, int k, int m)
    {
        int i;

        if (k == m)
        {
            for (i = 0; i <= m; i++)
            {
                row[i] = list[i];
            }

            for (int g = 0; g <= m; g++)//column
            {
                for (int j = g + 1; j <= m; j++)
                {
                    if ((row[g] + j) == row[j])
                    {
                        ifGoodPermutation = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if((row[g] - j) == [j])
                    {
                        ifGoodPermutation = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (ifGoodPermutation == 0)
                    break;
            }

            if (ifGoodPermutation == 1)
            {
                for (i = 0; i <= m; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(row[i]);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = k; i <= m; i++)
            {
                swapNumbers(ref list[k], ref list[i]);
                ifGoodPermutation = 1;
                PrintPermutation(list, k + 1, m);
                swapNumbers(ref list[k], ref list[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to summarize what the 8-queen problem is. We aren't all chess experts  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle

Comment: Side note: you can use `(list[k], list[i]) = (list[i], list[k]);` instead of `swapNumbers(ref list[k], ref list[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest implementing a *enumeration*, generator: we want enumerate valid queen positions:

```
    private static IEnumerable<int[]> Queens(int n) {
      if (n <= 0)
        yield break;
      
      int[] position = new int[n];

      if (n == 1) {
        yield return position;
        yield break;
      }

      while (true) {
        for (int file = 1; file < n; ) {
          int rank = position[file];

          if (position.Take(file).Select((r, c) => r == rank || 
                rank - r == file - c || 
                rank - r == c - file).Any(x => x)) {
            while (position[file] >= n - 1) {
              position[file] = 0;

              if (--file < 0)
                yield break;
            }

            position[file] += 1;
          }
          else 
            file += 1;
        }

        yield return position.ToArray();

        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i)
          if (++position[i] >= n)
            position[i] = 0;
          else
            break;
      }
    }
```

Having this generator, we can represent queen postions as we like:

```
var result = Queens(8)
  .Select(solution => string.Join(" ", solution.Select((r, f) => $"{(char)('A' + f)}{r + 1}")));

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Output:** (`92` lines):

```
A1 B5 C8 D6 E3 F7 G2 H4
A1 B6 C8 D3 E7 F4 G2 H5
A1 B7 C4 D6 E8 F2 G5 H3
A1 B7 C5 D8 E2 F4 G6 H3
A2 B4 C6 D8 E3 F1 G7 H5
A2 B5 C7 D1 E3 F8 G6 H4
A2 B5 C7 D4 E1 F8 G6 H3
A2 B6 C1 D7 E4 F8 G3 H5
A2 B6 C8 D3 E1 F4 G7 H5
A2 B7 C3 D6 E8 F5 G1 H4
A2 B7 C5 D8 E1 F4 G6 H3
A2 B8 C6 D1 E3 F5 G7 H4
A3 B1 C7 D5 E8 F2 G4 H6
...
A8 B3 C1 D6 E2 F5 G7 H4
A8 B4 C1 D3 E6 F2 G7 H5
```